# How to get all array's items equal

Tags: c

You're given two arrays a1,a2,...,an and b1,b2,...,bn. In each step you can set ai = ai -bi if ai >= bi. Determine the minimum number of steps required to make all a's equal. If it's not possible, then print -1.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define YES 1
#define NO 0

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    int a[5] = {5,7,10,5,15};
    int b[5] = {2,2,1,3,5};

    // Counting steps
    int change = YES;
    int steps = 0;

    do {
        change = NO;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (a[i] >= b[i]) {
                a[i] -= b[i];
                steps++;
                change = YES;
            }
        }

    } while (change);

    // Checking if all a's are equal
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        if (a[i] != a[i+1]) {
            printf("-1\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    printf("steps: %d\n", steps);

    return 0;
}
```

The issue is that with that sample data it's expected to get 8 as result, but i can't figure out how can this be possible. I've tried to do manual tests with pen and paper getting these results:

```
// Base data
a = {5, 7, 10, 5, 15};
b = {2, 2, 1, 3, 5};

// After the operations
a = {3, 5, 9, 2, 10}; // First iteration
a = {1, 3, 8, 2, 5}; // Second iteration
a = {1, 1, 7, 2, 0}; // Third iteration
a = {1, 1, 6, 2, 0}; // Fourth iteration
```

At this point, i think there's no way that all a's will ever become equal because all indexes except one have reached the lowest possible value and yet aren't equal, so the program should return -1, which is actually what the program is printing out.

What's wrong with my approach and how could i get the expected result of 8?

Comment: If the expected answer is 8, then I think that you've misinterpreted the question. Posting the original problem statement may help.

Comment: Can you help me understand how a step is defined here? I'm taking it as in the problem says "In each step you can set ai = ai -bi if ai >= bi.", that's why i'm counting one step every time an item changes. Besides, is it possible to get all items equal keeping in mind the base array's data?

Comment: @user3386109 I've posted the original problem statement, here's the link if you want to take a look: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/make-all-equal-90a21ab2/
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it a question of "can" versus "must"?  Since the minimum value in a is 5 (twice), you don't need to adjust a[0] or a[3] at all; one subtraction takes a[1] to the value 5; 5 subtractions gets a[2] to 5; and 2 subtractions gets a[4] to 5.  That's a total of 8 subtractions.  If the value in a[4] was initially 14 instead of 15,, you'd have a different problem — I'm not sure what the steps would be, but the uniform value in the a array would be smaller, possibly even negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change a[1] from 7 to 5 by subtracting 2 once (one step). Change a[2] from 10 to 5 by subtracting 1 five times (five steps). Change a[4] from 15 to 5 by subtracting 5 twice (two steps). That is eight steps, and then each  a[i] is five.

For a general algorithm, the largest element in a must be reduced to be no greater than the smallest. Do that, then repeat until all elements are the same or the largest element cannot be reduced (because it is less than its partner in b).